# Resharper Keyboard shortcut Go to next issue and display and fix issue?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

Is there a keyboard shortcut to use in ReSharper to see suggestions and apply them? When I inspect code issues in a Solution, I find it slow to use the mouse to move from one issue/recommendation to the next, and see each suggestion.

I'd like to know a shortcuts for:

1. Navigating to the next issue/suggestion
2. Display possible fixes and apply them.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could use:

1. Go to next issue or suggestion <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PgDown</kbd>.
2. Display possible fixes and apply them <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once to see possible fixes twice to apply them.

You can also refer to the [default ReSharper keymap (Visual Studio scheme)](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper_DefaultKeymap_VSscheme.pdf) for more keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: If you have the IntelliJ IDEA shortcuts the first one would be F12. And you can go to the previous issues/suggestions with Sihft+Alt+PgDown or Shift+F12

Comment: [ReSharper help - Navigate code issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Design_time_Inspection.html#navigating)

Answer (score 13):

> Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard

Search for `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextErrorInSolution` and `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextHighlight` and give them whatever shortcut you like.  Cesar is correct with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> solution (`ReSharper_QuickFix`).  Also, the navigation shortcuts he mentions are `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextOccurence` and `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoPreviousOccurence`, though those last two seem best suited for the results of *Find Usages*, etc.

Comment: GoToNextOccurence works for me - (Ctrl-Alt-PgDn) navigates through the Inspection Results window

Answer (score 9):

To go to the **next** error in the **entire solution**: <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +   <kbd>PgDown</kbd>

To go to **previous** error in the **entire solution**: <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +   <kbd>PgUp</kbd>

This will save you from opening each files individually.

Comment: For me this worked after activating "solution wide analysis" in r# options > code inspection

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the StyleCop plugin for ReSharper, you can use the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to move to the next issue.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut has been modified by default :

To navigate to next issue/warning : <kbd>F2</kbd>

Display possible fixes and apply them : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html)

Comment: That's IntelliJ IDEA, not ReSharper.